# Sql query not working with date between

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My sql squery seems not be not working, any idea why?

```
SELECT 
    PH, 
    Chlorine, 
    Temperature, 
    Date, 
    Time 
FROM googlechart
 Where Date BETWEEN '2014-03-19' AND '2014-03-21' order by Date, Time;
```

Comment: "not working" - **how?**

Comment: no entries for this date range?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: database date format ?

Comment: show your database date format ?

Comment: Is `time` time of day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    PH, 
    Chlorine, 
    Temperature, 
    Date, 
    Time 
FROM googlechart
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-03-19' AND '2014-03-21'
ORDER BY Date, Time;
```

You have missed the WHERE.

Comment: Found problem, seeing blind on own code! Sorry.

Comment: @AK47 I edited the code twice to make it more readable and accidentaly, I have added the where clause, which was missing from the initial post.

Comment: @user3270211 no problem. That's fine.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 SELECT 
    PH, 
    Chlorine, 
    Temperature, 
    Date, 
    Time 
FROM googlechart
Where Date BETWEEN cast('2014-03-19' as datetime) 
AND cast('2014-03-21' as datetime) order by Date, Time;
```